# Whiile compiling SELECT DISTINCT column FROM database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hello I'm New To Android. so I don't know so much about android. and that's why I'm stuck in one place.
I make  app which  user save and delete their data. but when delete Button are click then my app are stop working and log cat message show the error.

```
SQLiteException: no such table while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT column FROM database
```

so now i want to know what is **SELECT DISTINCT** can anyone tell me what is it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Umh yeah. probably "database" table does not exist!

Comment: The correct syntax is `SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName FROM TableName`

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT column FROM database` the select distinct is a sql-query to get every possible result just once even if there are multiple results. it is normally run on 1 column in 1 table. therefore if you have column number like `1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5` the result would be `1,2,3,4,5`.

right syntax is `SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT is an SQL command for returning columns from a DB. DISTINCT means that the rows returned from the SELECT command contain only unique values in each selected column, in other words, there can't be duplicate values in any of the columns.

Your command is returning an error as it is trying to access a table named "Database", which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT DISTINCT** returns resultset without duplicates of a column in a table.It can be done for a single column only.

Comment: i have the table but it's show same message so what i do now creating a new database java file ?